# Citrus Framework - Can a variable be assigned from a response?

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I'm trying to test the following two REST calls:

**Request 1**

```
GET getLatestVersion
Response: {"version": 10}
```

**Request 2**

```
POST getVersionData (body={"version": 10})
Response: {"version": 10, data: [...]}
```

Is it possible to assign the "version" from Request 1 to a variable to use in Request 2 within the same test?

```
@CitrusTest(name = "SimpleIT.getVersionTest")
public void getVersionTest() { 
    // Request 1
    http()
            .client("restClient")
            .send()
            .get("/getLatestVersion")
            .accept("application/json");

    http()
            .client("restClient")
            .receive()
            .response(HttpStatus.OK)
            .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
            // Can the version be assigned to a variable here?
            .payload("{\"version\":10}");

    // Request 2
    http()
            .client("restClient")
            .send()
            .post("/getVersionData")
            // Idealy this would be a Citrus variable from the previous response
            .payload("{\"version\":10}")
            .accept("application/json");

    http()
            .client("restClient")
            .receive()
            .response(HttpStatus.OK)
            .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
            .payload("\"version\": 10, data: [...]");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JsonPath expressions:

```
http()
    .client("restClient")
    .receive()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .extractFromPayload("$.version", "apiVersion")
    .payload("{\"version\":\"@ignore@\"}");
```

Or you can use the create variable matcher in payload:

```
http()
    .client("restClient")
    .receive()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .payload("{\"version\":\"@variable('apiVersion')@\"}");
```

Both options will create a new test variable `apiVersion` that you can reference with `${apiVersion}` in further test actions.

Comment: Thanks Christoph!

Answer (score 0):

One approach that works is to extract the value from the TestContext and assign it as a variable

```
@CitrusTest(name = "SimpleIT.getVersionTest")
@Test
public void getVersionTest(@CitrusResource TestContext context) {

    http(httpActionBuilder -> httpActionBuilder
        .client("restClient")
        .send()
        .get("/getLatestVersion")
        .name("request1")
        .accept("application/json")
    );

    http(httpActionBuilder -> httpActionBuilder
        .client("restClient")
        .receive()
        .response(HttpStatus.OK)
        .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
        .payload("{\"version\":\"@greaterThan(0)@\"}")
    );

    // This extracts the version and assigns it as a variable
    groovy(action -> action.script(new ClassPathResource("addVariable.groovy")));

    http(httpActionBuilder -> httpActionBuilder
            .client("restClient")
            .send()
            .post("/getVersionData")
            .payload("{\"version\":${versionId}}")
            .accept("application/json")
    );

    http(httpActionBuilder -> httpActionBuilder
            .client("restClient")
            .receive()
            .response(HttpStatus.OK)
            .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    );
}
```

**addVariable.groovy**

This extracts the variable from the response and adds it to the TestContext.

```
import com.consol.citrus.message.Message
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

Message message = context.getMessageStore().getMessage("receive(restClient)");

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def payload = jsonSlurper.parseText((String) message.getPayload())

// Set the version as a variable in the TestContext
context.getVariables().put("versionId", payload.version)
```

*Questions*

- Is there a neater way to do this?
- Is there a way to name the messages within the MessageStore?