# Setting variables and expected values in Citrus Framework

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I have the following scenario I want to test:

1. Perform a call to service A, get the number of elements in a JsonArray
2. Call service B to perform a given action
3. Perform a call to service A again, to verify that the JsonArray has a new element on it

PS: There is no correlation between the service B call in step 2 and the verification in the step 3. I just can verify that the element count increased in 1.

- I can perform step 1 using citrus `http()` and `.extractFromPayload()` and add it to a variable
- I can perform step 2 with another `http()` call

However I am stuck at step 3, since I can't modify the value of the variable taken in the step 1. I have tried using `action(new AbstractTestAction() {...})` but they don't happen in between the test so it is not working.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted a solution from [Citrus Framework - Can a variable be assigned from a response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143927/). I was able to accomplish this via:

Adding this step to the test (before making the Step 3 above):

`groovy(new ClassPathResource("addVariable.groovy"));`

This is the content of `addVariable.groovy`

```
int expected = context.getVariable("currentDataXYZ").toInteger() + 1
context.getVariables().put("expectedDataXYZ", expected.toString())
```

I think it is a bit cumbersome, but it works! If there is a cleaner way of doing it, would be nice, or maybe a feature request :)